# Arduino while loop with or condition

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, button

How do I write a program to wait (delay) until one out of two buttons pressed? I have written a program to wait until a single button is pressed. It's working fine. However, if I extend it to second button it's not working. Pls help on this.

1. `while (digitalRead(bt_Select) == HIGH) {}` -- working.
2. `while (digitalRead(bt_Select) == HIGH || digitalRead(bt_Reject) == HIGH) {}` -- Not working.

Complete code:

```cpp
const int bt_Select = 2;
const int bt_Reject = 3;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  pinMode(bt_Select, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(bt_Reject, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Pl input:");

  while (digitalRead(bt_Select) == HIGH {} // This is the line I change
      
  if (digitalRead(bt_Select) == LOW) {
    Serial.println("Select Button pressed:");
    delay(250);
    Serial.println("");
  }

  if (digitalRead(bt_Reject) == LOW) {
    Serial.println("Reject Button pressed:");
    delay(250);
    Serial.println("");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while (digitalRead(bt_Select)==HIGH||digitalRead(bt_Reject)==HIGH){}`

should be

`while (digitalRead(bt_Select)==HIGH&&digitalRead(bt_Reject)==HIGH){}`

The first loop would break only if you press both buttons at once. I believe you are trying to break if either button is pressed.

Comment: yes I try to break if either button is pressed.

Comment: Thank you it's working.. 5n

Comment: however i confused how it could works?!*

Comment: @AkRikas Your code stays in the while loop when one of the buttons is `HIGH` and the other code when both are `HIGH`. Does this answer your question?